# java - Is JavaFX SortedList stable?

Tags: sorting, javafx

Let's say I want to sort a list twice, using different comparators each, with the first comparator taking precedence over the second. Is it OK to simply call the SortedList constructor twice, with one call for each comparator?

To clarify why I want to do this, let's say I have an unordered list of `Student` objects, which have the fields `Age` and `Name`. Now, the end result that I want to achieve is a list of `Student`, where the younger students will appear earlier in the list. However, in the case where there is a group of students with the same age, I want them to appear in sorted-name order. The catch is that I'm restricted to using the comparators which are given to me - which in this case compares the students by either age or name depending on which comparator is specified.

Sorting the list twice, first by name and then by age a la Radix Sort, solves the problem but only if the sorting algorithm involved is stable. I know `Collections.sort` is stable, but I'm not sure if `SortedList` exerts the same behaviour.

I like J Atkin's `thenComparing` answer, and I think this is what I will do, but now I'm just curious whether `SortedList` is stable.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You'd just end up with the last sorting order.

Comment: Can you clarify (perhaps by showing some code)? If you mean `new SortedList<>(new SortedList<>(someList, comparator1), comparator2)`, then I think it will do what you want (though it's not necessarily the best way).

Comment: @James_D Yep, that's what I mean.

Comment: @EvanKnowles That depends on the stability of the sorting algorithm involved. Most of the time, you're right, but I'm concerned about the cases where the second comparison returns true for equals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's stable. I just checked the implementation of `SortedList` and discovered a class named `SortHelper` that performs sorting for a `SortedList`. In it there is a method named `sort`:

```
public <T> int[] sort(T[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex, Comparator<? super T> c) {
....
    if (c==null)
        mergeSort(aux, a, fromIndex, toIndex, -fromIndex);
```

So `SortedList` uses [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), which is stable.

All that is well and good, however, a cleaner way would be to combine the comparators using [`thenComparing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-):

```
sortAge.thenComparing(sortName))
```

Comment: That doesn't really prove it's stable though, it might just happen to preserve the order for equal elements in that particular case... Use `thenComparing(...)` is much better anyway; it will guarantee stability and perform much better (as it is only doing one sort, not two).

Comment: @James_D 6 months later and I found the (fairly) definitive answer.